# Git log --graph format query

Tags: git, logging, graph, branch

I have this graph log (`git log --oneline --all --decorate --graph`)
 in my testgit repository:

```
* 760711e (HEAD -> dev, master) Initial commit
```

If I do a commit in my `dev` branch, the graph log would be this:

```
* c710544 (HEAD -> dev) Initial dev
* 760711e (master) Initial commit
```

My question is: If `dev` is a branch, why does not it look like this?:

```
  * c710544 (HEAD -> dev) Initial dev
 /
* 760711e (master) Initial commit
```

I mean, is a branch, no? Why it appear as if it would part of `master` branch?
Maybe a dumb question, but is only curiosity. :P

Comment: Besides [lucanLepus's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43954340/1256452) (which is good, and upvoted, and accepted :-) ) it's worth considering that there are lots of ways to draw graphs, and `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`—mmenmonic: A D O G) has the constraint that it has only plain text, not graphics-drawing. Other visualizers sometimes do a better job. Git does pretty good considering its limitations...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you may know, branches in git are basically just pointers to commits

your git log command now shows all the commits any branch points to, and the hisory of these commits back to the initial commit.

in your example, master points to the initial commit, dev points to a commit that has the initial commit as direct predecessor

therefore git log just shows the two commits, as they cover all existing branches and their history back to the initial commit.

once you advance your master branch (by commiting while having it checked out) git log will show something more like this

```
*      master
| *    dev
|/
*      initial commit
```

which might be what you expect

Comment: Good. I'm clueless, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In this visualization, every commit at and below a branch name are on that branch. So `master` has one commit while `dev`  has two. In other words, both of the commits are on `dev`.  The first commit is on both  branches.

Comment: Oh, I see... And there is a way to get the lg graph that I mean?

Comment: @Moige I don't understand what you are asking.